# Open one collapse item and closes all the others with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do I use Bootstrap 5 collapses component this way? I wish that when a collapse item opens, all the other closes. Reading the documentation I found this:

"If parent is provided, then all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when this collapsible item is shown. (similar to traditional accordion behavior - this is dependent on the card

class). The attribute has to be set on the target collapsible area."

But I didn't understand how it works exactly. I tried this but doesn't work:

```
    <section class="faq">
<span class="text-center text-uppercase mx-auto d-block title"> FAQ </span> 
<div class="faq-wrapper">
<div class="question">
   <span class="title">
      <div class="toggler p1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> 
         <span class="line1 line-2-active">
         </span>
         <span class="line2 ">
         </span> 
      </div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?          
   </span>
   <div class="text-white mt-2 answer a1 collapse show" id="collapseExample1" >
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna                aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.             </p>
      <div class="divider"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
   <span class="title"  >
      <div class="toggler p2" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> <span class="line1"></span> <span class="line2"></span> </div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?          
   </span>
   <div class="text-white mt-2 answer a1 collapse" id="collapseExample2" data-bs-parent="#collapseExample1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna             aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis             aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse             </p> 
      <div class="divider"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="question">
   <span class="title" >
      <div class="toggler p3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample3"> <span class="line1"></span> <span class="line2"></span> </div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?          
   </span>
   <div class="text-white mt-2 answer a1 collapse" id="collapseExample3" data-bs-parent="#collapseExample2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna                aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.             </p>
      <div class="divider"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gustavo-bove/pen/MWbeaOj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you want to use Collapses component rather then Accordion?

Have you looked at Accordion?
url: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

HTML:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```